# Reaction log saying the name of the message author instead of person who reacted (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am working on a bot in discord.py, and I am trying to create a reaction log in my bot log, but instead of saying the person who reacted, it says the message author. Can someone help me?

Here is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message
    channel = message.guild.get_channel(812838695169949727)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="{} added a reaction!".format(message.author.name), description="", color=0xffa500)
    embed.add_field(name="This is the channel:", value=str(message.channel), inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="This is the message:", value=message.content, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="This is the reaction:", value=str(reaction), inline=True)

    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2):

`reaction.message.author` is the original author of the message. The user who reacted is the `user` parameter of the `on_reaction_add` event handler, so to get their name you should use `user.name` instead of `message.author.name` on the 5th line.